# IE Screenscraping using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

im trying to click on the "Next" link in a webpage but the link.innerHTML cannot find "Next"

the HTML Code looks like this

a href="queue_monitor.do?task_name=WAITCUST&pager_offset=250&actionType=next"> 
                           Next
                                                /a>

when I edit the Link from the webpage to remove the next line and the spaces it works...

```
For Each ie In objshell.Windows
    If TypeName(ie.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        If InStr(ie.Document.Title, "Monitor") Then
            ie.Visible = False
            ie.Visible = True

            Set html = ie.Document
            Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

                For Each link In ElementCol

                    If TRIM(link.innerHTML) = "Next" Then

                        link.Click

                            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
                            Application.SendKeys ("^a")
                            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
                            Application.SendKeys ("^c")
                            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WAITCUST Raw").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial
                            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:07")
                    End If

                Next link

        End If
    End If
Next ie
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the URL to the site? it would be easier to test the code

Comment: sorry I cant its an internal site

Comment: what you posted is part of the url to the 2nd webpage   http://example.com/queue_monitor.do?task_name=WAITCUST&pager_offset=250&actionType=next

Comment: so instead of looking for "Next" ill look for the "a" anchor with the specific url? is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You could target via the end part of the `href` value for the target element using a CSS selector:

```
[href$='actionType=next']
```

This is an attribute selector that looks for an `href` whose value ends (`$`) with `actionType=next`

```
ie.document.querySelector("actionType=next").Click
```

CSS query on your HTML:

[image]